# Is hotel confirmation needed at UK immigration?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I have a question regarding travelling to the UK from Germany.

I am an Indian passport holder who has a blue card and a permanent job.

I applied for my UK visitor visa from Germany where I said I plan to book a hotel for my stay on my application.

But by the time I got my visa the prices of hotel were so incredible high, I decided to take my cousin’s offer to stay at her place instead. (She lives and works there with her family)

Now would I need any kind of document or anything from her such as a letter of invitation to stay at her place?
Will I need to produce such a document at immigration, because I already have a valid visa.

Answer (score 1):

Having a valid visa doesn’t guarantee entry. On arrival you may still need to show that you meet the ‘genuine visitor’ rules in V4.2 of the [UK visitor immigration rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor).

V4.3 states that accommodation may be provided by a third party only if that third party:

(a) has a genuine professional or personal relationship with the applicant; and

(b) is not, or will not be, in breach of immigration laws at the time of the decision or the applicant’s entry to the UK as a Visitor; and

(c) can and will provide support to the applicant for the intended duration of the applicant’s stay as a Visitor.

If you stated in your visa application that you would be staying in an hotel, the Immigration Officer may ask to see proof. Since you now plan to stay with a relative, you should be prepared to show evidence of that instead.

Comment: I indicated that I will stay at my cousin's place. I provided an invitation letter from him along with a copy of his passport and his visa.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, then I’ll ask her to provide me with the necessary documents ☺️

@AnishSheela my only concern is I stated in my application that I would opt for a hotel and now that’s changed. So I wonder if that would be an issue.

Comment: @Emma Plans change. Staying with family is perfectly normal thing. Your explanation is perfectly reasonable. Answer truthfully as mentioned in question. You will be fine. :)

Comment: @AnishSheela did you also provide your cousins home rental/ownership documents? Or just the ones you mentioned above?

Comment: @Emma Just invitation letter. Also attached the council tax document (I don't think it was necessary).

Comment: @AnishSheela thank you!